# Reading a config file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a config file like this:

```
rawfile=input.raw
encfile=encoded.enc
decfile=decoded.raw
width=512
height=512
rle=1
quantfile=matrix.txt 
logfile=log.txt
```

Having this function:

```
void Compression::readConfigFile(char * input)
{
    string lineBuf;
    string optionBuf;
    std::ifstream confFile(input);

    if ( confFile.is_open() )
    {
        while ( getline( confFile, lineBuf ) )
        {
            optionBuf = "rawfile=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->rawfile = lineBuf.c_str();
            }
            optionBuf = "encfile=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->encfile = lineBuf.c_str();
            }
            optionBuf = "decfile=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->encfile = lineBuf.c_str();
            }
            optionBuf = "width=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->width = atoi( lineBuf.c_str() );
            }
            optionBuf = "height=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->height = atoi( lineBuf.c_str() );
            }
            optionBuf = "rle=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->rle = atoi( lineBuf.c_str() );
            }
            optionBuf = "quantfile=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length());
                this->matrix = lineBuf.c_str();
            }
            optionBuf = "logfile=";
            if ( ( ( int )lineBuf.find(optionBuf) ) != -1 )
            {
                lineBuf.erase( 0, optionBuf.length() );
                this->logfile = lineBuf.c_str();
            }
            confFile.close();

        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Can't open file: " << input << endl;
}
```

But it doesn't work. My ints are 0 or some big number. My strings are still empty.

Can someone help me please?

Kind regards,

Comment: if you want to find "option=" at the start of the line, might be better to use string.compare() instead of find and limit the length of the comparison to the optionbuf length. Find will find it anywhere in the line.

Comment: The whole approach seems flawed.  For starters, the numerous `lineBuf.c_str()`: if he's saving the results as a `char const*`, this isn't going to work, and if he's saving them as an `std::string`, it's unnecessary.  But more generally, I'd split the string at the first `'='`, and go from there.  With some sort of map mapping the key to the address of member which is to be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't you rather close the file outside of the while loop ?

```
while() {
    ...
}
confFile.close();
```